# Related Rates Problem With Ladder

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A 30-foot ladder rests vertically against a wall. A bug starts at the bottom of the ladder and climbs up at a rate of 3.5 feet per minute. At the same time, the foot of the ladder is being pulled along the ground at a rate of 1.5 feet per minute until the top of the ladder reaches the ground. Let $x$ be the distance of the bug from the wall at time $t$.

I got $x(t)=-.175t^2 +1.5t$ to represent the horizontal distance of the bug to the wall as a function of time, $t$.

The question also asks:

> When the bug is farthest from the wall how high is it?
>
> When the bug reaches the top of the ladder how high is it from the ground?
>
> What speed does the bug need to climb in order to reach the top at the same time the top of the ladder reaches the ground?

What I am confused about is what equation/steps do I need to find in order to compare the equation I found with, which will allow me to find the answers. I looked up related rates problems, but was confused because this problem has the ladder moving down, but none have one with something going up. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be horizontal and $y$ vertical.  I would first express the bug position along the ladder as a function of t: $z=3.5t$.  Then you need to find out where this point along the ladder is.  The foot of the ladder is at $(1.5t, 0)$, so the top of the ladder is at $(0,what?)$.  From these two points you should be able to find the $(x,y)$ coordinates of the bug as a function of time, which will answer all your questions.

Added and corrected:  the foot of the ladder is at $(1.5t,0)$ and the top is at $(0,\sqrt{900-2.25t^2})$  The bug is $\frac{3.5t}{30}$ of the way along the ladder, so is at $(1.5t(1-\frac{3.5t}{30}),\frac{3.5t}{30}\sqrt{900-2.25t^2})$

Comment: Done-just lost the last $